# How to rewrite 4 grep expressions to 1 regexp expression in R?

Tags: regex, r

I want to assign a value to these patterns.

What is the best way to rewrite this in one line?

```
fullset$Title[grep("Dona.", fullset$Name, fixed = TRUE)] <- "Mrs."
fullset$Title[grep("Lady.", fullset$Name, fixed = TRUE)] <- "Mrs."
fullset$Title[grep("Mme.", fullset$Name, fixed = TRUE)] <- "Mrs."
fullset$Title[grep("Countess.", fullset$Name, fixed = TRUE)] <- "Mrs."
```

Comment: Maybe `fullset$Title[grep("(Dona\\.|Lady\\.|Mme\\.|Countess\\.)", fullset$Name)]<- "Mrs."`

Answer (score 1):

You could group them together using a regular expression.

```
fullset$Title[grep('(Dona|Lady|Mme|Countess)\\.', fullset$Name)] <- 'Mrs.'
```